# MySQL date range using PHP variables and STR_TO_DATE

Tags: php, mysql

After passing in values to `from` and `to` via this call:

```
getTransactions.php?from=05/01/17&to=05/31/17
```

I get nothing returned from the MySQL call:

```
$data = $pdoProducts->query("SELECT * FROM `transactions`
        WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%y') 
        BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE($from, '%m/%d/%y') 
        AND STR_TO_DATE($to, '%m/%d/%y')")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

I have several other calls that do work using the `STR_TO_DATE` method and the date in the table, so I know that the data in the table is correctly formatted.

However, I still cannot get this date range to work. Am I formatting something wrong?

Comment: What do $from and $to look like?  Are they url encoded?  Try echoing the query to the screen and running it manually.

Comment: here is the echo "05/01/17  05/31/17"

Comment: Output and run the query manually - just to see what it does.

Comment: Unless formatted date strings are quoted, they will be treated as an arithmetic operation.... `05/01/17` = `5` divided by `1` divided by `17` = `0.2941176470588235`

Comment: It's normally better to do the date conversion in PHP and keep MySQL as neutral as possible. The preferred format there is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Using a `DATE` column can massively improve performance since it can be properly indexed.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data only as arguments on `execute` . In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for advice on how to avoid problem like this.

Comment: So should I add quotes to the variables in the php call?

Comment: It doesn't look like its performing arithmetic operations because echoing out $from, $to, and $data outputs '05/01/17  05/31/17 []'

Comment: Echoing out your SQL statement doesn't tell you that SQL is doing the arithmetic division

Answer (score 0):

If Data type is `varchar`

```
SELECT * FROM user_attendance
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('21/05/2014', '%d/%m/%Y') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('21/06/2014', '%d/%m/%Y')
```